# Need to Return JSoup Conncetion.Response as Response from Spring MVC Controller

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc, jsoup

I am working on Spring MVC and Jsoup and have written the Spring Controller which send the Jsoup Connection.Response which is obtained from the below code:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/getPage")
public Connection.Response getJsoupResponsePage(Principal loggedInUser,
                                 HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {

Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect(url)
                               .data("j_username", "username")
                               .data("j_password", "password")
                               .method(Method.POST).execute();
 return res;
}
```

I need complete Connection.Response Object to be opened in the new tab of the browser.

I am calling jquery ajax request from the browser and url is the different domain name so I have already opened the session of that url before sending request to **/getPage**.

```
var ajax_params;
ajax_params = {
            url : "getPage",
            type : "POST",
            cache : false,

            success : function(response) {
                console.log(response);  
            },  error : function() {
                console.log("ERROR");
            }
    }
$.ajax(ajax_params);
```

I am getting 406 Not Acceptable and I am getting error in ajax call.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.sunplus</groupId>
<artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
<version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>myproject</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- For Spring Boot when running in non-embedded Tomcat -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.servlet.jsp-api.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Password Validation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.passay</groupId>
        <artifactId>passay</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Data JPA dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> -->
    <!-- <groupId>xml-apis</groupId> -->
    <!-- <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId> -->
    <!-- <version>1.4.01</version> -->
    <!-- </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- DB dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>${guava.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <!-- <scope>runtime</scope> --> <!-- some spring dependencies need to compile against jcl -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency> <!-- needed to bridge to slf4j for projects that use the log4j APIs directly -->
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.restassured</groupId>
        <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>myproject</finalName>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java-version}</source>
                <target>${java-version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${cargo-maven2-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <wait>true</wait>
                <container>
                    <containerId>tomcat8x</containerId>
                    <type>embedded</type>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <!-- <provPersistenceTarget>cargo</provPersistenceTarget> -->
                    </systemProperties>
                </container>
                <configuration>
                    <properties>
                        <cargo.servlet.port>8081</cargo.servlet.port>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>

<properties>
    <java-version>1.7</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>4.1.6.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.springframework.security.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</org.springframework.security.version>

    <!-- logging -->
    <org.slf4j.version>1.7.12</org.slf4j.version>
    <logback.version>1.1.3</logback.version>

    <!-- javax jsp -->
    <javax.servlet.jsp-api.version>2.3.2-b01</javax.servlet.jsp-api.version>

    <!-- Inject -->
    <javax.inject.version>1</javax.inject.version>

    <!-- Spring Data Jpa -->
    <spring-data-jpa.version>1.8.0.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>

    <!-- guava -->
    <guava.version>18.0</guava.version>

    <!-- maven -->
    <cargo-maven2-plugin.version>1.4.15</cargo-maven2-plugin.version>

</properties>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: So you want to send a Java object in your response and have the client side somehow use this? Maybe you want to send the (String) content from this Connection.Response instance??

Comment: update your question with version of spring and your pom.xml

Comment: I am using Spring 4.1.6.RELEASE and Jsoup 1.8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

406 http status code is `not acceptable`.
Which means in your case spring cannot `Could not find acceptable representation` for your `Connection.Response` object.
 Change it to `String` and return the body of the JSOUP response .

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/page")
public @ResponseBody String getJsoupResponsePage(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {

    Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("http://abv.bg")
            .data("j_username", "username")
            .data("j_password", "password")
            .method(Connection.Method.POST).execute();
    return res.body();
}
```

and call it with this ajax method:

```
var ajax_params = {
            url : "page",
            type : "POST",
            cache : false,
            success : function(response) {
                console.log(response);  
            },  error : function() {
                console.log("ERROR");
            }
    }
$.ajax(ajax_params);
```

ps: I'm a little bit puzzled what you are trying to do. Just solving the `406` error.